# How to use combineReducers when having a custom react context hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, reduce, react-context

I made a custom context:

```
interface IContextProps {
  state: StateType;
  dispatch: Dispatch<Action>;
}

const Context = React.createContext({} as IContextProps);

export const useCustomContext = (): IContextProps => {
  return React.useContext(Context);
};

export default Context;
```

State type:

```
export type StateType = {
  items: Array<DataItems>;
  global: StateTypeGlobal;
};
```

I had one big reducer which I wanted to split and combine with combineReducer

```
export const combineReducers = (slices) => (state, action) =>
  Object.keys(slices).reduce(
    (acc, prop) => ({
      ...acc,
      [prop]: slices[prop](acc[prop], action),
    }),
    state
  );
```

When I initialize the provider:

```
  const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    global: globalReducer,
    items: ItemReducer,
  });
  
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(rootReducer, initalState);

  const store = React.useMemo(() => [state, dispatch], [state, dispatch]);

  <Context.Provider value={store}>
  </Context.Provider>
```

here I get an error saying:

> Type 'any[]' is missing the following properties from type
> 'IContextProps': state, dispatchts(2739) index.d.ts(328, 9): The
> expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on
> type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps'

Which made sense since I am sending in an Array and not an object. This made me change my customContext to:

```
const Context = React.createContext([] as Array<IContextProps>);

export const useCustomContext = (): Array<IContextProps> => {
  return React.useContext(Context);
};

export default Context;
```

**Problem**

How do I extract state?

In a file I previosly did:

```
const { state, dispatch } = useCustomContext();
```

This worked but now gives me the following error:

> Property 'state' does not exist on type 'IContextProps[]'.

> Property 'dispatch' does not exist on type 'IContextProps[]'.

EDIT:

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-tfu2cu?file=Context%2Findex.tsx,Reducer%2Findex.tsx,Components%2FDummyComponent.tsx,App.tsx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really related to React or context; you're simply mixing up your types.

In the first example, your context's type is an object, but you're passing an array to the `Provider`. A simpler example with the same problem:

```js
interface IContextProps {
  state: StateType;
  dispatch: Dispatch<Action>;
}

const example = (value: IContextProps) => {};

const value: any[] = [state, dispatch];

/*
 * Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IContextProps'.
 * Type 'any[]' is missing the following properties from type 'IContextProps':
 *   state, dispatch ts(2345)
 */
example(value);
```

Instead of the array in the `useMemo`, you want an object that matches the `IContextProps` interface, e.g.:

```js
// value is an object
const store = React.useMemo(() => ({ state, dispatch }), [state, dispatch]);

<Context.Provider value={store}>
</Context.Provider>
```

Comment: This was my original attmept but... when I tried to dispatch a change event for the reducer I got maximum numbers of re-renders. stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-tfu2cu?file=Context%2Findex.tsx,index.tsx,Components%2FDummyComponent.tsx,App.tsx

Remove comments from dummycomponent to reproduce. 

After that I thought my implementation was wrong hence the above attempt.
If this is correct then how do I get arround the re-render?

Comment: A few things. First of all, don't put `state` in the dependencies array of `useEffect`. The effect changes the state, and the effect runs every time state changes, looping forever. Instead, extract `items` from state and use it in the dependency array. Also, you shouldn't have the local `items` state AND the `items` from the context. Pick one or the other.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve with the `combineReducers`, but I would recommend against trying to recreate redux until you're a little more familiar with it. The point of redux's `combineReducers` is so that each reducer gets it's own top-level key in the main state object, and no 2 reducers ever touch the same parts. What you have now is going to jumble it all together, like: `{"items":[],"global":{"global":{},"items":[{"HelloWorld":"HelloWorld"},{"HelloWorld":"HelloWorld2"}]}}`. One `items` at the top, and another nested under `global`

Comment: I do agree, im novice to the react context and I belive in learn by doing an that is basicaly what this is. If it's not 2 much to ask would you be willing to provide a working example based on my stackblitz?

Comment: Honestly, I just wouldn't use `useReducer`... ever. It's modeled after older-style Redux, which was awful, particularly when using TypeScript.

For context, I generally just use distinct providers, where everything to do with that particular bit of state is isolated, rather than trying to deal with one big root state where everything is munged together. The reducer syntax is cumbersome compared to simple functions. Here's an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-cherry-fnuh46

Comment: The recommended way to use Redux nowadays is Redux Toolkit, which is WAY better. https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today

If you just want to understand the old reducers concept, you can skip down the left nav there to "Redux Fundaments", which is basically the tutorial from before the toolkit was created. Try getting it working with the library before trying to recreate the library (that has over 3,500 commits!). But honestly, I'm glad they phased that structure out. It was ridiculously overcomplicated.

Comment: If you're dead set on continuing the path you're on, separate all of your reducers, and be aware that the `state` passed to each of them is actually a subsection of the root state. E.g. if your `combineReducers` puts `ItemsReducer` under `items`, the `state` it gets is `<root>.items`, NOT the root state initialized in the app.